# Peer to Peer Voice Call Twilio

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, twilio

I want to develop an app like WhatsApp. My app functionality is to do voice call peer to peer like WhatsApp do for Voice Calling. I want to use Twilio to do this. I researched on their website but little bit confused at Programmable Voice, Twilio Client, and Programmable Video. I also want to do video calling. But for now, I want to do peer to peer(App to App) voice calling. I am confused at Which API's should I use to do a voice call. 
I developed demo with a programmable voice from this link - https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift and It's working but doesn't fulfill my requirements like I want to call between users.
Please tell me which API I should use to do App to App voice call from Twilio.
Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: use sinch API for app to app call ,,

Comment: I know but I have to use Twilio API as per requirement.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50409940/2437655

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are trying to do app to app video or audio chat, then I recommend you use the [Twilio Video API](http://twilio.com/docs/api/video). With Video you can request access to just audio or audio and video, so it can cover both.

Check out the [sample applications for iOS and Android](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/quickstart-sample-apps) and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you so much.   So if I want to do audio call then should I remove videoTracks from TVIConnectOptions ?

Comment: Yes, just don't request the VideoTracks. :)

Comment: @philnash Is there a way to route the audio to the normal "phone call" speaker, instead of the actual speaker? Kind of like switching cameras, but switching audio output instead?

Comment: @mbm29414 I believe you need to set the [`TVIAudioController`'s `audioOutput`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.7/docs/Classes/TVIAudioController.html#//api/name/audioOutput) to [`TVIAudioOutputVoiceChatDefault`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.7/docs/Constants/TVIAudioOutput.html).

Comment: @philnash I tried doing that, but I can't seem to change the audio output when using Twilio Video. It would kind of make sense to me that video chat only allows speaker output. Do you guys have a "best practices" for mimicking a phone call, but without using phone numbers (i.e., like a video chat but without video)? It seems like the answer you gave has some limitations that I need to get around.

Comment: It's probably not the best idea to discuss this in the comments of a different question. Can you ask a new question with what you've done to try to set the audio output and we can try to solve that.